# Issue with redirect urls when using Federated Login with AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I'm trying to use OpenID with AppEngine, and I've setup a simple `/_ah/login` page for signing in with Google.

But it seems when I use `users.create_login_url(dest_url='/some/page?foo=bar&fizz=buzz')`, which returns:

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id&continue=https://myapp.appspot.com/some/page?foo=bar&fizz=buzz
```

when eventually I'm redirected to the `dest_url`, the second parameter (`fizz=buzz`) is missing.

Is this a bug/limitation on `create_login_url()`?

Comment: have you tried url encoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a bug in federated login. Reported here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3249

Workaround: Escape the ampersand twice

`& -> %26 -> %2526`

```
url ='/some/page?foo=bar&fizz=buzz'
import urllib    
url = urllib.quote(urllib.quote(url_re))
users.create_login_url(dest_url=url)
```

or replace the `&` with `%2526`.